# Why we generate random normal distributed numbers trough the inverse function?

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, inverse-function, random, cumulative-distribution-functions

I was thinking this, suppose you have a linear congruential generator that generates $n$ random numbers, we then make those integer numbers in doubles. So we have $n$ random numbers from $0$ to $1$.

Now suppose we need to normally distributed numbers, so we would input each number in a function that returns the quantile of a normal distribution associated with the number. Then we have our pseudo-randomly distributed numbers.

My question is: why do we use the inverse cumulative function of the normal distribution instead of the "ordinary" cumulative function?

Thank's.

Comment: This is a general method that (theoretically) applies to *any* (not necessarily normal) target distribution, see [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). However, it is not actually very practical to sample from the normal distribution as the inverse c.d.f. (the error function) is not elementary. We rather use the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) in this case.

Comment: @nejimban I just started studying this so forgive my naivness. Thank's for pointing me to the wikipedia page, really one of the best wiki pages I've seen! My question anyway is: why we do not use the $F(x)$ but $F^-1(x)$ ?

Comment: It would simply not work with $F$. Note that $F\colon\Bbb R\to[0,1]$. So applying $F$ to a random number will give you a $[0,1]$-valued random variable. On the contrary, $F^{-1}\colon[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ maps into the domain of the real variable you want to simulate. You may want to look at the (rather easy) proof of the Inverse transform sampling and see how/why it is the *inverse* of $F$ that occurs.

Comment: I'll do it. Thank's for your kind response.